# javascript to click a row and fire off that rows "onclick" event

Tags: php, javascript

I have a table:

```
<table>
<th>Title</th>
<th>Artist</th>
<th>Length</th>
<tbody>
<?php
foreach ($lib as $name)
{
echo "<tr onmouseover=\"ChangeColor(this, true);\" 
              onmouseout=\"ChangeColor(this, false);\" 
              onclick=\"dispSong('".$name->title. "','".$name->url."', this);\"><td>".$name->title."</td><td>".$name->artist."</td><td>".$name->time."</td></tr>";
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

In javascript I can find the next row:

```
    function dispSong(theSong, url, elem)
  {

    document.getElementById('currSong').innerHTML = theSong;
    row = elem.rowIndex; 
    var song = document.getElementById('mp3');
    song.src = url;
    song.load();
  }

  function nextSong()
  {
    if (row == null) row = 1;
    else{
    alert(row+1);
    }
    document.getElementById('tr')[row].click;
    var song = document.getElementById('mp3');
    alert(song);
    song.src = url;
    song.load();
  }
```

I have a button called next that calls the nextSong function when it is clicked. I am wondering if I can some how programatically click the next row when the next button is pressed.

Comment: This line of code certainly won't work: `document.getElementById('tr')[row].click` as `tr` is a tagname not an element ID.  I'm not sure what you're trying to do so don't know what to suggest.  Perhaps you mean to be using `getElementsByTagName()`?

Comment: Your HTML is flawed. You should put the `th`s inside a `thead`; currently they're forced into the `tbody`.

Comment: @jfriend00 ah.... yes... should be using getElementByTag...

Comment: thanks @pimvdb I'll fix that... still learning HTML

Comment: If you're open to using a cross-browser framework like jQuery (which makes this stuff a lot easier), then here's some sample code you can look at related to your application:  http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/FeM5p/.  In your code, I personally wouldn't try to simulate a click.  Just call the function you need to call directly rather than simulate a click.

Comment: I'll just use jQuery.. i've heard a lot of good stuff about its ease of use... thanks for the sample code!

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code should allow you to fire an event programmatically:

```
var target = document.getElementsByTagName('tr')[row];
if(document.dispatchEvent) { // W3C
    var oEvent = document.createEvent( "MouseEvents" );
    oEvent.initMouseEvent("click", true, true,window, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    target.dispatchEvent( oEvent );
}
else if(document.fireEvent) { // IE
    target.fireEvent("onclick");
}
```

Some documentation about the initMouseEvent at [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.initMouseEvent).

**Edit:**

This works like a charm with `<a/>` element but does not seem to work on `' though...

Comment: Your first line of code: `var target = document.getElementById('tr')[row];` will not work because `tr` is a tagname, not an id and `getElementById` does not return an array.

Comment: @jfriend00 what if i changed it to getElementByTag, would that work? or do i need to have ids?

Comment: `getElementByTag` is not a DOM method.  Programming requires exact syntax.  As I mentioned in my previous comment on your main post, the method for getting elements by tag name is `getElementsByTagName()`.  That would only work the way you are trying to use it if there are no other `tr` elements anywhere in your page which is not a wise assumption or design restriction.